# How to change gradle's setting?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I updated Android Studio to version 3.6 (Windows) and now i can't find how to change gradle to work offline
in AS settings!!

[here is settings panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MBnB.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check at View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle when Gradle window opens, it appears there.
[image: Toggle Offline Mode]