# How can I change gradle to work offline in Android Studio Bumblebee for a Flutter project

Tags: flutter, gradle, android-studio-bumblebee

I have Android Studio Bumblebee on ubuntu and I need to set my Gradle to work offline. I can't find the gradle tab to try out some of the suggestions such as this one.

[How to change Gradle's setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60420185/how-to-change-gradles-setting)

Going to settings as suggested in one of the solutions here [How to configure Gradle to work "offline" (using cached dependencies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171524/how-to-configure-gradle-to-work-offline-using-cached-dependencies) does not work as the option for offline is not available under the Gradle setting.

I need to set the Gradle to work offline so that I can run my flutter application which is failing when downloading the Gradle due to poor network I presume. I have tried downloading the Gradle manually and linking but each time I run the app and there is a network failure it deletes the manually inserted Gradle zip file and tries to download again .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the project was not properly linked with the gradle.build file when I opened it since it's a flutter project.

To fix this close the project and then go to Open > Then select the build.gradle file. This will then open the project as a gradle project and the gradle pane will appear.